# jQuery: DOM editing of selection option label doesn't work in Chrome / Webkit?

Tags: jquery, dom, webkit, html-select

As a result of an Ajax query, I am renaming a html *option* tag (the label, not the value).
For this, I do the following

```
$('#my-select-box option:selected').html(answer.label); // answer.label is a string
```

Works fine everywhere, but strangely not on Chrome. Well, Chrome actually gets the new label (I can output it in the console) but doesn't render it. The select option looks as if it had kept the previous label.

I am using jQuery 1.7.1, Chromium 16.0.912.77

Any clues ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would say the *right* way to do it is to manipulate the `text` property:

```
$('#my-select-box option:selected').text(answer.label);
```

[**Demo, tested in Chrome.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/qnq2d/)

Comment: Ok thanks, it works in the example, as expected but strangely in my own application it does not work. I just don't get where the problem is, I am doing the editing after an ajax query but still, don't see why